# Projecting the vertices of a tennis court from 3D to 2D is not working

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

**Background**

I've defined a tennis court with 3D points, and I'm trying to use OpenCV to project the 3D points as a 2D image.

Below are the 3D points I'm using to define the tennis court.  For reference:

- Left on the court is -X and Right is +X,
- Up is the -Y and Down is +Y, and
- Far side of net is +Z and Close side is -Z.
- Point (0,0,0) is the intersection of the left side line with the net line (basically the left net post).

```
def DefineCourtPoints():
    objp = {}
    objp[1] = [0,0,39] # 1.  Intersection of the upper base line with the left side line
    objp[2] = [0,0,-39] # 2.  Intersection of the lower base line with the left side line
    objp[3] = [36,0,-39] # 3.  Intersection of the lower base line with the right side line
    objp[4] = [36,0,39] # 4.  Intersection of the upper base line with the right side line  
    objp[5] = [4.5,0,39] # 5.  Intersection of the upper base line with the left singles line
    objp[6] = [4.5,0,-39] # 6.  Intersection of the lower base line with the left singles line
    objp[7] = [31.5,0,-39] # 7.  Intersection of the lower base line with the right singles line
    objp[8] = [31.5,0,39] # 8.  Intersection of the upper base line with the right singles line
    objp[9] = [4.5,0,21] # 9.  Intersection of the left singles line with the upper service line
    objp[10] = [31.5,0,21] # 10.  Intersection of the right singles line with the upper service line
    objp[11] = [4.5,0,-21] # 11.  Intersection of the left singles line with the lower service line
    objp[12] = [31.5,0,-21] # 12.  Intersection of the right singles line with the lower service line
    objp[13] = [18,0,21] # 13.  Intersection of the upper service line with the center service line
    objp[14] = [18,0,-21] # 14.  Intersection of the lower service line with the center service line
    objp[15] = [0,0,0] # 15.  Intersection of the left side line with the net line (this will be considered (0,0) )
    objp[16] = [36,0,0] # 16.  Intersection of the right side line with the net line

    return objp
```

For additional reference, here are the intrinsic matrix and distortion parameters for my camera (which were obtained using OpenCV and have been validated):

```
intrinsic_mtx = np.array([
    [1882.77177, 0.0, 973.572122],
    [0.0, 1880.83035, 537.299982],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
])

distortion = np.array([0.232714433, -1.35119878, -0.00188551612, 0.00166434182, 2.50351701])
```

Here is the code I use to project each of the 3D points to 2D, and to graph the points/lines using Matplotlib.

```
def ProjectPoints(intrinsic_mtx, distortion, R, T, objp)
    x_points = []
    y_points = []

    # Loop through each of the 3D points and project them to 2D.
    for index in objp: 
        2d_point = cv2.projectPoints(
                        np.array(objp[index], dtype=np.float64),
                        cv2.Rodrigues(R)[0],
                        T,
                        intrinsic_mtx, 
                        distortion
                     )[0][0][0]

        print(2d_point)
        x_points.append(2d_point[0])
        y_points.append(2d_point[1])

    # Graph the court boundary.
    lines = [(1,2), # A line exists between point 1 and 2...
            (2,3), # A line exists between point 2 and 3...
            (3,4), # A line exists between point 3 and 4...
            (4,1)] # A line exists between point 4 and 1...

    x_lines = list()
    y_lines = list()
    for pair in lines:
        for i in range(2):
            x_lines.append(x_points[pair[i]-1])
            y_lines.append(y_points[pair[i]-1])
        # Append None to separate the lines.
        x_lines.append(None)
        y_lines.append(None)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x_points, y_points)
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.plot(x_lines, y_lines, c = 'r')
    plt.show()
```

**Problem**

*When I project the points and graph them, I expect to get something looking like a tennis court, but I just get a blob of points!*

To troubleshoot, I decided to graph just outer edges of the court using the four corners of the court (which are the first four points in DefineCourtPoints).  I expected to see a rectangle or parallelogram as these are valid projections of a rectangle.  However, I get stuff like the following, which doesn't really make any sense since it has crossed lines:

[image: Projection output... not what I'm expecting]

The above result was obtained using `R = [0, 0, 0]`
and a `T = [0, -10, 0]`

Here are the coordinates of the four points for the above result, showing that I didn't cause the weird shape by somehow graphing the lines in the wrong order:

```
# Intersection of the upper base line with the left side line
[973.572122 , 1019.56417431]

# Intersection of the lower base line with the left side 
line
[973.572122 , 55.03578969]

# Intersection of the lower base line with the right side 
line
[-764.37105031, 55.03578969]

# Intersection of the upper base line with the right side line
[2711.51529431 , 1019.56417431]
```

**Question**

Why am I getting such weird projections for such a simple 3D object as a rectangle/tennis court boundary?

Is anyone getting the same results that I'm getting?

Thanks!

**Try it yourself**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def DefineCourtPoints(): # Just the corners of the court.
    objp = {}
    objp[1] = [0,0,39] # 1.  Intersection of the upper base line with the left side line
    objp[2] = [0,0,-39] # 2.  Intersection of the lower base line with the left side line
    objp[3] = [36,0,-39] # 3.  Intersection of the lower base line with the right side line
    objp[4] = [36,0,39] # 4.  Intersection of the upper base line with the right side line  

objp = DefineCourtPoints()
intrinsic_mtx = np.array([
    [1882.77177, 0.0, 973.572122],
    [0.0, 1880.83035, 537.299982],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
])

distortion = np.array([0.232714433, -1.35119878, -0.00188551612, 0.00166434182, 2.50351701])
R = np.array([0,0,0])
T = np.array([0,-10,0])
ProjectPoints(intrinsic_mtx, distortion, R, T, objp)
```

Comment: a [mre] would be handy.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - Thank you, I just added a "Try it yourself" section that I hope helps.

Comment: (And I added the graphing code to my post)

Comment: strange flavor of python. identifiers like `2d_point` can't start with a number. please try to avoid pseudo-code. best remove all uses of dictionaries too.

Comment: the coordinate systems look unusual. actually, the whole code feels weird. suddenly appending `None`s for some reason... and some other stuff. I'd have to rewrite it all to make sense of it and narrow the potential error space.

Comment: I can tell that you're way too close to the object, (78 x 36, when you're 10 units away...) so your picture can't possibly have been made with these values.

Comment: a likely issue is that you're iterating over a dictionary's keys, but you use some oldish python where dictionary keys don't maintain insertion order... or you have an off-by-one because you chose your indices to start at 1. or a combination of that.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/dca6099bfa5203ca77698ee87c8795a1

Comment: The main issue appears to have been the values I used for the rotation and translation matrices.  After going through @ChristophRackwitz 's demo on github, I changed my rotation and translation matrices to match what Christoph had in his demo, and I also used an array instead of a dictionary for storing the object points.  These changes gave me the result I was looking for.  Thanks Christoph!